# Host index.html in subfolders of S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Static website hosting is working in the root directory, but this is not working for me:

```
my.bucket/index.html
my.bucket/subfolder/index.html
```

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.bucket works as expected

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.bucket/subfolder doesn't work (Access Denied)

Is this possible?

Comment: Does s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.bucket/subfolder/index.html work? How about my.bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/subfolder/index.html?

Comment: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.bucket/subfolder/index.html renders the page correctly
my.bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/subfolder/index.html gets Access denied!

Comment: You should be using `http://your.bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/...` if you want the website hosting features, including index documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) three ways to access a static website hosted in AWS.

- The S3 bucket name
- The CDN name.  (which is what the "host a static website" wizard tells you to use)
- The "Static website hosting endpoint" which is listed on the S3 bucket management page

Only the "static website hosting endpoint" filters incoming requests to give Apache like behaviour; S3 is a RESTful API for storing files with no concept of subfolders.

*If you have used the wizard, there is "Manage file in S3" in tiny text at the bottom left of the screen, which will open up the correct page in the console for you, then click the 'properties' button.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the permissions of the sub-folder as well to make it publicly accessible.

Comment: Already done that (otherwise I wouldn't be able to directly access it?)